# What is the proper term for non-function-pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

In C++ you can pass in "function types", which are like function pointers but they are just the type of the function and not a pointer to it. For example:

```
template< typename T >
class MyTemplateClass
{
   // ...
};

// ... and later...

MyTemplateClass<void (int, int)> mtc;
```

What is the proper name for this form? Is this a "Function Type"?

### Update:

I edited my example to be a little more clear. However, keep in mind the main part of the sample I'm trying to point out is the `void (int, int)` part.

Comment: What does the class do? If it's just a type for a function maybe you could call it 'Function Class'? Because you're defining a class of a particular type of function. I'm just inventing new words here :P

Comment: What is the proper name for a **type**? Whether it's a function, object, integral, pointer, or whatever I do believe it's *still* a **type**.

Comment: Ug.  Don't hit me.  But this actually works?  In the standard, I see that you can use "typename".  That seems to be the only grammatical choice, since "class" and "template" obviously don't work.  Is void(int, int) just crazy longhand for a typename?  What compiler is this?  And again... feel free to school me.  I realize I've never seen this before.

Comment: Yeah, it's basically a function.  Most people typedef it to something.  `void(int, int)` is a function type that takes two `int`'s and returns a `void`.  It's much more common to see: `typedef void (&func_vii)(int,int); MyTemplateClass<func_vii localfunc> {...`

Comment: @Michael: `void(int,int)` is the specification of a function type: the type of a function that takes two `int` arguments and has no return value. In this case, its being used as the argument to a template with a type parameter, presumably declared somewhere as `template <typename Function> class MyTemplateClass;`.

Comment: @Michael: For an example use of function types, you can have a look at `std::function` (or `Boost.Function`).

Comment: @AJG85: You're being far too philosophical. When communicating with other programmers it is essential to have proper communication. Knowing what to call this type will help both communication and documentation. Also, when you introduce type constraints (concepts), the disambiguation becomes even more important.

Comment: @Robert: Perhaps, but this is a philosophical question. You can call it *fargument* so long as the term and definition is accepted by your audience. Terms are like slang the only thing that matters is the meaning is understood by those using it.

Comment: @AJG85: It's not a question about philosophy, but about terminology. If you use the terminology of the language standard, then there's no need to ask your audience for acceptance; anyone familiar with the standard will understand you.

Comment: @Mike: If I had a dollar for every programmer who was familiar with the standard I'd be poor. All I meant is the *best* term is subjective.

Comment: @AJG85. I didn't ask for the *best* term, I asked for the *proper term*. I hardly find that subjective, especially since one answer clearly outlines sections in the standard that use the term "function type".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the term is "function type".

Comment: Not that I don't think this is a good name, but doesn't a function type refer to both the name of the type and its definition?  Maybe I'm being too nitpicky.  (I'm probably being too nit-picky).

Comment: @Michael: To be completely nitpicky, `void(int,int)` is the type-specifier of a function type. Only user-defined types (which do not include function types) have names and definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a "function type"

8.3.5[dcl.fct] says

> 1. In a declaration T D where D has the form `D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seq`*opt* `ref-qualifier`*opt* `exception-specification`*opt* `attribute-specifier-seq`*opt* [...]
> 2. In a declaration T D where D has the form  `D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seq`*opt* `ref-qualifier`*opt* `exception-specification`*opt*`attribute-specifier-seq`*opt* `trailing-return-type` [...]
> 3. A type of either form is a *function type*.

Comment: I made the comment to @Mike, and trust me, this is just curiousity now, but in 8.3.5, it is speaking of both the name of the type and it's complete definition.  The "function type" from 8.3.5 would not be acceptable grammar within a template parameter.

Comment: @Michael Hays right, it's not acceptable as a template parameter, that's where `template<typename Func>` goes. It's acceptable as a template argument. `14.3[temp.arg]/2` has a nice example with `f<int()>();`

Answer (score 1):

They're only like function pointers in that the syntax is a little similar; otherwise they have nothing to do with function pointers (i.e. they don't hold any data or any such thing). However, David Rodriguez points out below that they might be considered related in the same way that `int` is related to `int*`.

Anyhow, they're just types though, like `int` (not *an* `int`, just `int`).

Comment: I would not go as far as saying that they are unrelated to function pointers: they are related to function pointers in the same way that `int` is related to an int pointer `int*`.